# Why worry about make a pure javascript/jquery widget when I can load it into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, widget

I mean, I use to have this widget :

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/widget.js?type=normal" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="archie-container"></div>
```

that check if jquery is on the hosted website; else it load it and do some ajax/jsonp request. As suggested by this [tutorial](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/).

Well, I've noticed big trobules about CSS parents, integrate other jquery plugins (like cycle) and manage data between this "interface" and the ajax call.

Why I should do it when I can use a sngle iframe? I also noticed that, if I load jquery from widget.js, and (of course) i put it into the iframe (so I can manage separate functions) the library are taken from cache. So there isn't any overload.

Is it good enough for you this approch? Or I am missing somethings?

I also noticed that 90% of widgets (like FB, twitter, etc) use this strategy (with iframe).

Comment: You can use any technique that works for you. It all depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iframe keeps isolated from the rest of the page.

I recomend read this:
[iframes vs ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768222/iframes-vs-ajax)

if something isolated from the rest of the page, and simple go with iframe. If the widget interacts with the rest of the page go AJAX.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial about "iframe is cached due to the library from the host page". Didn't know it before...that's why I always though about avoid iframe! But its nice...

Comment: @markzzz: The easiest way around that problem is to add a timestamp parameter to the query to guarantee it's unique.  It can also be done with telling the browser not to cache the content in the headers.

Comment: @dj_segfault : no, in fact I want caching :) I didnt know this was the standard behaviour...! I'd like to read more about this...