# How to stop loading of header, footer and menu on each link clicked?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, tiles

I am creating a java application where I am using spring MVC and hibernate.

Add for Header, Footer and Menu I am using **tiles** because these are same for all pages.

Now my question is on each link click whole page is loading instead I want to load only body part.(Means I want to stop loading Header, Footer and Menu each time).

How its possible??

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making AJAX calls from your JSPs to Spring controller. [Detailed explanation is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179519/1097933)