# Getting links from db and displaying them in another div

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, connection

i was thinking on starting on a new website project. But i have one question!
I want a two tabled layout like:

```
|-------------|
|     |       |
|     |       |
|     |       |
|     |       |
|     |       |
|-------------|
```

On the left i would like to have the listed item and link like (page.php?id=1 and so on)
And when the user clicks the link on the left, the data will be showed in the rigth column.
Is this possible with HTML, CSS and PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible, although you will have to use Javascript as well.

Comment: How is this possible? Or, how can i do this ?

Comment: If you want links to open in the right without reloading the page then you need to use an `ìframe` in the right, or even better use AJAX.

Comment: Ye, i was thinking about using ifram, but i would like not to, never learned AJAX but i guess it cant be that hard am i right ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Well, if you knew about the iframe and also the AJAX solution, then I really can't understand why you posted a question here. SO it's not supposed to be a *dynamic tutorial*. :/

Comment: I dind hear about the AJAX solution, but i thought about the iframe solution:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To do this, you need to use AJAX.

Here is a beginners tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

After you read up on that, and understand the basics (if you don't know javascript, you may want to look into some more tutorials), you can move on to jQuery(a Javascript framework). You can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for example. There are many options of doing this, the main thing is to start.

Trial and error is the most important methodology you have at your disposal, if you want to learn. Good luck !

**PS:**

Since there are 2 options of doing what you want (iFrames and AJAX) - you should read this question: [iframes vs ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768222/iframes-vs-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AJAX or use iframe on the right

```
<iframe name="frname"></iframe>
```

and target your links to it

```
 <a href="http://site.com" target="frname">Link</a>
```